# What is the symbol of the transcendental numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, transcendental-numbers

the symbol of the natural numbers is $\mathbb{N}$, for integers it is $\mathbb{Z}$, for rationals it is $\mathbb{Q}$, for irrationals it is $\mathbb{I}$, and for transcendental numbers it is **not found**

what is the symbol? and why wikipedia doesn't put this symbol in their website?

the wikipedia page i found was [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number)

Comment: A link would be nice.

Comment: this is the wikipedia page for transcendental numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number

Comment: $\mathbb{T}$ is not ideal because that is often used for the circle.

Comment: ok, i will add the link

Comment: But the [Wikipedia page for _irrational_ numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) doesn't seem to mention your symbol $\Bbb I$, either. I don't think $\Bbb I$ is universally accepted.

Comment: my math teacher said the symbol was $\mathbb{I}$, what would be the other symbol?

Comment: There is no standard symbol for the irrationals.  People usually write $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ if one is needed.  Likewise, the non-real complex numbers are $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$, and the transcendentals can be denoted $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb A$, where $\mathbb A$ is the set of algebraic numbers.

Comment: There is the sequence of universally recognised symbols $\Bbb N,\Bbb Z,\Bbb Q,\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb H$ (quaternions), $\Bbb O$ (octonions)...and as far as I am aware, it stops there. $\Bbb I$ would be an anomaly here, because it is not a ring.

Comment: I don't understand the close vote...  This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to ask. The fact that the OP was misinformed by their teacher is not their fault.

Comment: We generally give sets of numbers a letter when they are a ring.  I’ve seen your example of $\mathbb I$ a few times, but it is rare enough, I wouldn’t use it without defining it before use. I’m not even sure there is a consistently used letter for the algebraic reals, which is actually a ring (the complement of the transcendentals.)

Comment: @mweiss: And what's more, the close reason was 'this question is not about mathematics'... Very bizarre.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have seen $\mathbb A$ used for algebraic numbers.

Comment: yeah question closed because it is not about math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard symbol for the set of transcendental numbers. If one needed to express it in symbols, it would probably be $\Bbb R \setminus \overline{\Bbb Q}$, with the understanding that $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ represents the algebraic closure of the rational numbers, that is, the algebraic numbers.

In the end, I would try avoiding using a symbol for this set whose English name "the transcendental numbers" is perfectly descriptive (just as I would for "the irrational numbers"); and if I did decide I needed a symbol for it, I would explicitly define the notation even if it had appeared in some other source.